# Firefox won't compute age - result is NAN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue when computing age based on a specified date in my react app. The code works on most browsers, but in **FIREFOX** I get a **NAN** value.

```
 function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date("2022-12-31");
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
   
  }
    const handleAgeSelect = (e) => {

    setBirthdate(birthdateInput.current.value)
    // const bd = birthdate.current.value
    console.log(birthdateInput.current.value);
   

    const computeAge = getAge(JSON.stringify(birthdateInput.current.value))
    const selectedAge = computeAge
   
     console.log("selected Age", selectedAge)
   
    setAge(selectedAge);

   
  };


//Here is the part of the form where the birthdate is captured.

<Form.Group controlId="birthdate">
                            <Form.Label>Birthdate</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                            type="date"
                            ref={birthdateInput}
                            placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                            onChange={handleAgeSelect}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group controlId="age" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                            <Form.Label>Age:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                
                                type="number"
                                defaultValue={age}
                                ref={AgeInput}
                                onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            </Form.Group>
```

I am not sure why this does not work in Firefox, could someone help me out?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` --- why do you need it?

Comment: So what gets logged for `birthdateInput.current.value` ?

Comment: Consider using `valueAsDate` and `valueAsNumber` so you don't have to parse them yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redundant `JSON.stringify` that wraps a string in additional pair of double quotes `"`.

Then chrome happily parses that garbage, but FF not.

So the solution: don't run `JSON.stringify`, you don't need it.